# Does an IF-Statement checks every OR operator?

Tags: c++, performance, if-statement

At the moment I´m testing around with particles and have one important question.

```
if (condition a || condition b || condition c)
```

or

```
if(condition a)
        if(condition b)
             if(condition c){

}
```

Which is faster?

Comment: The two of them are not equivalent. Therefore you cannot say, which one is faster. 

However, the first is quite fast when you start with the condition, that is most likely true, because the subsequent conditions will not be executed. 

(For && it would be the other way around. Then the first one should be the one that is most likely false)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C++ uses what is known as *short-circuit* expression evaluation, which means that as soon as it encounters a term which determines the final result of the expression, (regardless of what the remaining terms may evaluate to,) it will stop evaluating terms.

Since `TRUE OR X` is `TRUE` regardless of the value of X, C++ will not bother evaluating X.

However, your cascaded `if` statement is ***not*** equivalent to the first expression.  It is equivalent to an expression with multiple ANDs not multiple ORs.

Answer (score 1):

This has likely been answered somewhere else before, but C++ uses the short circuit method, that is, if any condition passes, the rest are ignored (in the case of logical or: `|`).

The reverse is true for logical and: `&` - the first condition that fails short circuits the if statement and it exits early.

Here's an example:

```
if (condition a || condition b || condition c) {
 // This code will execute if condition a is true, condition a or b is true, or if all three are true
}

if (condition a && condition b && condition c) {
 // This code will only execute if all three are true, but if a is false, it will exit early, the same can be said for b
}
```